# Replacement for htmllib module in Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use the htmllib module but it's been removed from Python 3.0. Does anyone know what's the replacement for this module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't used it, but it looks like what you want is the [`html.parser`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.parser.html) library, and possibly also [`html.entity`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/html.entities.html).

Comment: html.parser is a poor replacement. One was a pleasant dom

Answer (score 10):

It is Superseded by HTMLParser see [Python library reorganization](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/)

Answer (score 1):

I heard Beautiful soup is getting a port to 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

I believe lxml has been ported to Python 3